# How to replace an aggregate null value by 0

Tags: sql-server, null, sum, aggregate

I need to calculate a percentage, based on the amount of money on an user account and group the data by the account ID. I make in my calculation a sum of every payment that is used. A problem is that I also need to show acocunts without payments. My idea was to use a CASE statement to check if the aggragate sum gives a null or a value. When it returns null, I replace it by 0.

I have following query

```
SELECT 
  DA.ACCOUNT_ID,
  ROUND((1 - ((CASE 
                WHEN SUM(FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY) IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY)
                ELSE 0
            END) / FAT.PERCENTAGE_INDICATOR)) * 100,0)  AS "Percentage"
FROM DIM_ACCOUNT DA
JOIN TRANSACTION_TABLE FAT ON FAT.ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID 
JOIN PAYMENTS_TABLE FPP ON FPP.ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID
GROUP BY DA.ACCOUNT_ID
```

But when I execute this with test data, it doesn't work. The account is not added in my list. Is something wrong with my NULL handling?

When I strip of the query and only do the sum at the payment table, I get following output:

> < null > (without spaces)

How can I make this work?

Comment: See may be SUM(whole case statement ....)

Comment: Why not just SUM(COALESCE(MyColumn,0))?    No CASE statement needed.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is ignored by aggregate functions like `sum/max/min...`
If all column values are `null` then it will give error.

`Sum(column)` cannot be `null`

```
SELECT sum(t.num) AS sum_val
FROM (
    SELECT null AS num
) t
```

> Operand data type NULL is invalid for sum operator

Answer (score 0):

if by 'without payments' you mean with no related records in `PAYMENTS_TABLE` then use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  DA.ACCOUNT_ID,
  ROUND((1 - (ISNULL(SUM(FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY), 0) / FAT.PERCENTAGE_INDICATOR)) * 100,0)  AS "Percentage"
FROM DIM_ACCOUNT DA
JOIN TRANSACTION_TABLE FAT ON FAT.ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID 
LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS_TABLE FPP ON FPP.ACCOUNT_ID = DA.ID
GROUP BY DA.ACCOUNT_ID;
```

a `INNER JOIN` does exclude the accounts without payments because requires a matching record in all the involved tables.